# Specific word for man who has an ungentlemanly attitude towards a romantic partner

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to remember a very specific (old-fashioned but not completely uncommon term) for a man who behaves in an ungentlemanly way towards a romantic partner --for example, a young man who boasts crudely to his friends about his liaison with a young woman who had asked him to keep it a secret.

The word is not lout or churl or chauvinist.  The connotations are of someone who is ungrateful and immature --someone who is unappreciative of the sexual favors they are receiving.

*Sample Sentence:*  I didn't mean to be a _____ when I insulted the breakfast you brought me in bed this morning.

Comment: Is "breakfast in bed" a double-entendre now? Unless it is, the two words you're requesting are significantly different, unless it's a [guy like this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4R5wZs8cxI) :)

Comment: @medica I assumed this was meant to refer to a post-coitus breakfast. :)

Comment: @JohnClifford - I tried, but I really don't follow. How does that compute? One example refers to a braggart, the other to an ingrate. Both are boors.

Comment: @medica Funnily enough cad still works either way. :)

Comment: I'm not sure this question is really any more specific than *Word for someone you don't like*. Unless the sub-type is *someone you **did** like enough to have sex with them last night, but now find objectionable*.

Comment: "Jerk" is the first term that comes to mind.

Comment: Your 'unappreciative' works.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is drawing close votes.  It has a positive rating, it has a highly rated, accepted answer, and it includes a sample sentence, as specified for this tag.

Comment: @HotLicks +1 Not exactly what I had in mind but probably a nicer word. :P

Comment: Chris Brown...?

Comment: For some I'd think the word that encapsulates all and more of the behaviour you describe (immature, ungrateful, boorish, braggart) would simply be _man_...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you're looking for old-fashioned, the first thing that springs to mind is [***cad***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cad).

> a man who acts with deliberate disregard for another's feelings or rights
>
> *Merriam-Webster*

The Google definition backs this up as an appropriate answer:

> a man who behaves dishonourably, especially towards a woman.

as you did specify the behaviour would be towards a romantic partner, and this fits well.

Comment: Sounds more like a software term.

Comment: @Josh61 And insensitivity isn't specific to romance. :P But yeah, every time I see that word my mind fills it in with "Computer-aided Design" and I have fond memories of using TurboCAD as a kid. It's no less appropriate an answer, however. :)

Comment: "*You, sir, are a cad and a bounder!*" - there's a great entry in the Urban Dictionary for this phrase, here: (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cad+and+bounder). Presumably pronounced *ked* and *binder*, respectiveleh.

Comment: Sounds like pistols at dawn for you two.

Comment: I'd be interested to know which two people downvoted this, especially since the duplicate answer which was posted after mine only has one. :P

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was the word that was eluding me.  Amusingly, your link put me on the trail of an entire body of research around "dads vs cads"!

Comment: lol, my username is cad, it's just supposed to be an abbreviation for my full name, tho. Gotta change that username. :O

Comment: Just a warning: I'd consider this term archaic. I've heard it in passing, but never had an idea what it meant.

Comment: I think "old-fashioned but not completely uncommon" was accurate enough. It's definitely dated, but I think OP was aware of that. Should I edit it into my answer anyway?

Comment: @cad still works to ping you, cadaniluk ;-)

Answer (score 20):

I think you may be looking for the word ***[cad](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cad).***

> a man who behaves dishonorably or irresponsibly toward women.

The word has broader meanings, but my experience is that the specific meaning you seek is its usual meaning.

Synonyms [here](http://www.freethesaurus.com/cad).

Of course, if a man is *not* a cad, sex with a woman is not merely a favor that *she* does *him.*

Comment: Sorry Brian, [I beat you to this one by a minute](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316856/specific-word-for-man-who-has-an-ungentlemanly-attitude-towards-a-romantic-partn/316862#316862). :P

Comment: @JohnClifford, but by how many votes remains to be seen.

Comment: Touché, my friend. The game is afoot!

Answer (score 10):

You sir are a ***[bounder!](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bounder)***.

**Bounder** was popular around the turn of the last [century](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&case_insensitive=on&content=bounder&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cbounder%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbounder%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBounder%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBOUNDER%3B%2Cc0) and means:

> a man who behaves badly or in a way that is not moral, especially in his relationships with women.

Answer (score 8):

Consider, [***boor***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boor&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cboor%3B%2Cc0)

> A rude and insensitive person.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boor)

Comment: 'Boorish' would fit better."I didn't mean to be boorish..."

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer you're looking for is *cad*, not least because your example sentence necessitates a noun.

However, ***ungallant*** would be an appropriate adjective.

> **Ungallant:** lacking in courtesy or chivalry
>
> *I didn't mean to be so ungallant when I insulted the breakfast you brought me in bed this morning.*

<sub>Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014. (1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2014). Retrieved April 1 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ungallant</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**roué**

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rou%C3%A9)

[image]

**rake**

[Oxford learner's dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/rake_1)

[image]